# "False" arrow in an elementary topos

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

In "Topoi: The Categorial Analysis of Logic" by R. Goldblatt (page 117) the "false" arrow is defined based on the comutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0 @>0_1>> 1\\
@V ! V V @VV {\rm false} V\\
1 @>>{\rm true}> \Omega
\end{CD}
Now, the arrow into the final object is unique, so it seems that $0_1$ and the arrow denoted by $!$ must be the same. But this would make ${\rm true}={\rm false}$, which makes no sense. It looks like I am missing something very basic. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Perhaps try to see if your reasoning holds in the category of sets. That diagram commutes in any category for any object replacing 1.

Comment: Let me ask differently. What exactly is arrow $0_1$? Definition?

Comment: To Jaspreet. A clarification of the context. "false" arrow must be unique, which it clearly fails to be if only commutativity of the diagram is demanded in the definition. Sorry for not being clear in my statement of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understand. Hope you already have the answer. I’ve got nothing add unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arrow ${\rm false}$ is not defined by this square merely commuting, but by it being a pullback square.  So, you are correct that $0_1$ and $!$ are the same map, and so if you replaced ${\rm false}$ with ${\rm true}$ then the diagram would still commute.  However, to conclude that ${\rm true}={\rm false}$, you would need to know the diagram remains a pullback square, not just that it commutes.

(For some context, recall that $1\stackrel{{\rm true}}\to\Omega$ has the universal property that for any objects $A$ and $B$ and any monic morphism $f:A\to B$, there is a unique morphism $g:B\to \Omega$ such that $$\begin{CD}
A @>f>> B\\
@V ! V V @VVgV\\
1 @>>{\rm true}> \Omega
\end{CD}$$ is a pullback square.  So, this universal property is being applied to the monomorphism $0_1:0\to 1$ (which is just the unique morphism from $0$ to $1$), with the unique corresponding morphism $1\to\Omega$ being named ${\rm false}$.)